# Freezes in Firefox and Opera on CSS3 translate

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here are my css:

```
.portfolio-info:hover .portfolio-rate{
-webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
-moz-transform: translateX(100px);
-o-transform: translateX(100px);
-ms-transform: translateX(100px);
transform: translateX(100px);
```

}

```
.portfolio-doc, .portfolio-title, .portfolio-rate{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

In webkit oriented browsers it's look normal (get strange blinked text after animated block). But in FireFox and Opera...you should see this freezes. Where is the problem?

Comment: That is really strange... Could you put a part of your code here? http://www.jsfiddle.net That way you can check whether is is the browser or something on your website. I suppose it is something else in the system since this seems normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's someone plugin. In safe mode there are less freezes.

Answer (score 0):

I've already explored this bug and in Opera it can be fixed by setting
    .wrapper {
       -o-transform: translate(0px); 
    }

Comment: Here, wrapper is parent block of .portfolio-*?